# Is there anyway I can install any 2013+ Microsoft Office (Office 365 primarily because I have subscription of it), on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, office365

I started using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** dual boot with Windows and I m really starting to like Ubuntu. I have installed everything I need for my work and I m just left with Microsoft Office. I know Ubuntu has a built-in Libre Office but I don't feel comfortable with working on it because of some restrictions. Can anybody please help me in installing any **2013+ Microsoft Office**. My main priority is **Office 365** because I have a subscription to it. I would be really thankful

Comment: You can install it with [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36167) v6. See test results section in that webpage. Alternatively, you can use Office Web Apps. Also, you can try the free and open source version of [OnlyOffice](https://www.onlyoffice.com/download.aspx?from=downloadintegrationmenu). I started using LibreOffice with the Ribbon UI four years ago, and did not have to go back. If I ever come across .docx files which have incompatibility issues with LibreOffice, OnlyOffice always works for them.

Comment: LibreOffice can read/write Microsoft Office docs and many more. Highly recommended.  Also LibreOffice works cross platform: Windows, Mac, Linux.  You can let go of Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run Office 365 on a Linux machine by installing [CrossOver Linux](https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover)